# I would like to create a view where I can add tags to content

Tags: 7, hooks

I am pretty new to Drupal and have not created a module yet. I think the solution I am looking for will have to be a custom module and would like some tips on how to get started. Basically I have a content type of beverages. In that content type I have a term reference field that points to a term called featured. Basically I can check the Featured check box and that content will be displayed in a featured slider. The featured beverages need to be changed periodically. I would like to create a view that lists all of the beverages and from within the view I can change which ones are featured. Can anyone help me with at least a starting point on how to accomplish this? I am using Drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

First off, if all you need is a check box on your node form which toggles something as on or off - basically, a "Featured" state in this case - using taxonomy to achieve this is overkill. All you really need is an instance of a "Boolean" field.

Second, you can use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to operate on the results of a View. Basically, you can create a View with a column of check boxes much like the default content list in Drupal core. You can check a list of items - Beverage nodes in this case - and then select an operation to apply to the items you've checked. So yes, you'd need a custom module - a fairly simple one which would define "Make Featured/Unfeatured" actions, then implement callbacks to programmatically set/unset the "Featured" values on the selected nodes. See the [VBO development guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067) for instructions on how to implement this.

Comment: Not using a taxonomy term would be nice. I thought it was overkill, I tried using a boolean field, but for some reason I was having trouble getting only the "featured" content to show up when i did it that way. Basically the only reason for the "featured" field is to select which beverages show up in a slider on the home page. Even if I used a boolean field instead of taxonomy I would still need this same solution to change the "featured" state of each node. Thank you for your suggestions. I will take a look at VBO development.

Comment: OK I changed it from a taxonomy term to a boolean field and that is working great. Right now I have a view with a VBO field to change which nodes are "featured". It is not exactly user friendly though. I will play around with creating the module, but right now I'm pretty confused about how to do it. This is my first attempt at a module and I'm a little lost looking at the VBO development guide. Also I read somewhere that VBO doesn't play well with views with a search field. And being that I have over 300 beverage nodes I think a search field might be needed.

Comment: Yeah, this might be a little ambitious for someone's first module… Maybe you want to start off with something a little more straightforward until you get the basics down.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this without VBO? Maybe just using node_load and node_save? Or would it be better to use VBO to programatically update the nodes? I was thinking something like node_load($nid) $nid->featured_field[und][0][value] => 1